# Does "outside" as a preposition also mean "besides"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I read this line in an [online article](http://www.courant.com/sports/hc-chris-kathy-berman-courant-archives-20170510-story.html):

> And, **outside** a minor paunch and a rapidly expanding billfold, there's nothing heavy about him.

**Outside** here appears to mean "besides". Does it have this meaning as a preposition?

I looked through [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/outside) and [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outside), and there is no definition related to "apart from". MW does list "except", but there's no example sentences. I find this usage of **outside** unfamiliar to me, as it is not literal or physical, but figurative and less common than its physical meanings.

Comment: @choster I looked through [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/outside) and [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outside), and there is no definition related to _apart from_. MW does list _except_, but there's no example sentences, so I wasn't sure if it fits the usage I encountered in the article. So I accounted this question a worthwhile question.

Comment: A synonym would be **except for**.  Normal is **outside of**:  *Outside of a few scrapes and bruises, they emerged from the accident unscathed.*

Comment: I would advise learners to avoid using ***outside*** to mean ***apart from, besides, except*** in this way. That's from definition D3 in [the full OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/133978?redirectedFrom=outside#eid), but the only 2 citations are dated 1864 and 1943. And personally I find the cited usage dated / stilted / literary by comparison with the far more natural / idiomatic ***apart from***.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** 'besides' means 'in addition to', 'also', 'on top of that, or 'apart from' and is different from 'beside'. 'beside' has a physical connotation and would indicate that something is next to something else or on the side of something, e.g. 'at the side of', 'next to'.

**About your question:** 'outside' refers to that part that doesn't belong to what is considered to be inside. Outside the house, there is a road. Here the road could be next to the house without any space in between or with space in between (physically); the road could be beside the house, in front of the house, behind ...

I would recommend you to look such things up in e.g. Cambridge Advanced Learners Dictionary:

**beside** /bɪˈsaɪd/
preposition
1 at the side of, next to:
Come and sit here beside me.
Our school was built right beside a river.

2 compared to another person or thing:
Those books seem rather dull beside this one.

**beside the point**
not important or not related to the subject being discussed:
The fact that he doesn't want to come is beside the point - he should have been invited.

Answer (score 1):

I take some issue with this total injunction against the use of "outside" in the "except for" sense.  There is a connection between this usage and another cited by The *Living Oxford Dictionary* among others viz.,"*(attributive) not belonging to or coming from within a particular group"*.  Thus "outside" can be used to express distinctions between groups of things besides merely spatial distinctions.  The question is what are the natural limits of this expression's scope; can *outside of* refer to only concrete nouns or can it refer to abstract nouns; does it apply to common nouns or only proper nouns; is it restricted to some other natural class of things. A phrase like "outside the coal industry, no one thinks of coal as a clean fuel" seems perfectly fine.   The original example and the *scrapes and bruises* example both feel like a bit of a stretch here because both apply "outside of" to a group of *characteristics* and not a  group of people, or typically nominalized things.

Now I do think one must be careful of trying to apply a law of transitivity to synonyms here (perhaps someone can chime in with a more technical term for this).  In my example you could replace *outside of* with *besides* or *apart from* with only a slight adjustment in meaning; but the use of "outside" is preferable to those options because I am making a sharp distinction between the group of people who are part of the coal industry and those who are not. I do not think *besides* or *apart from* always connotes the same sense of sharp distinction. On the other hand, *except for*, while it seems to work well here, is so logically and grammatically basic that it applies to a wide range of cases that *outside of* would not.

Whether or not the extension of the use of *outside of* to include sets of characteristics or traits is idiomatic, I will leave up for continued debate - but these examples do not seem unintelligible to me. I suspect that it is an old usage, coming back to popularity.  I would say that the original phrase sounds more natural when it is slightly reworded to "And, outside *of having* a minor paunch and a rapidly expanding billfold, there's nothing heavy about him".